# how to add a top link in custom module at prefered position

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, toplinks

Can anyone let me know how to **add custom top lin**k on top menu after create an account link or at any place I want to put before/after.

I have tried with after attribute but its not changing position as I want.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your code which you have tried now.

Answer (score 0):

you can position the  with `before="account"` or `after="account"`

```
<referenceBlock name="header.links">           
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="cart" before="account">
                <arguments>
                 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Cart</argument>
                <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">checkout/cart</argument>          
                </arguments>            
      </block> 
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: I have used below screenshot code in xml:
http://prntscr.com/dl5cqz

but it still shows before account links given in below screenshot , i need contact link at last position:
http://prntscr.com/dl5d4b